# Synchronize on variable only when it is being updated

Tags: java, locking, synchronized

Usecase : Rotation of credentials for a datastore

What I want :

1. When updateCredentials is called, it will wait until it all threads are done fetching credentials (via the synchronize) to update the credentials to the new ones.
2. I DO NOT want calls to doSomeQuery making each other wait to fetch credentials.  This object can be used in multiple threads and its a wasteful wait.

Is there a method / pattern to achieve this?  The code sample below achieves item 1 but not item 2.

```
private Object credentialUpdate = new Object();

public void updateCredentials(String user, String pass) {
    synchronize(credentialUpdate) {
      this.user = user;
      this.pass = pass;
    }
}

public void doSomeQuery(String query) {
    String curUser;
    String curPass; 
    synchronize(credentialUpdate) {
        curUser = this.user;
        curPass;
    }
    // execute query
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your second point, neither your doSomeQueryMethod(). Can you explain what is your goal more precisely (what you want and no only what you don't want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock` and its implementation `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.  From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html):

> A ReadWriteLock maintains a pair of associated locks, one for read-only operations and one for writing. The read lock may be held simultaneously by multiple reader threads, so long as there are no writers. The write lock is exclusive.